# Does online multiplayer require a Nintendo online subscription?

Tags: nintendo-switch, overcooked-2, nintendo-switch-online

Does the online multiplayer for Overcooked 2 require a Nintendo Online subscription? I wasn't able to figure this out using the store description of the game, or on the game's website.

Comment: I’d assume so, as it’s not free.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.

The description in the eShop on the console says this:

> This software includes features that support online play. A Nintendo Switch Online membership (sold separately) is required for online play...Visit www.nintendo.com/switch-online for more information.

---

To make sure that this notice isn’t put on every game with online content no matter if it is free to play online or not, I checked *Fortnite*’s page and it didn’t have the notice.

<sub>(I cut out irrelevant legal stuff from the quote).</sub>