# Do you need Nintendo Online membership to play Overcooked 2 with friends on the same console?

Tags: overcooked-2, nintendo-switch-online

To play Overcooked 2 do you need a Nintendo Online membership if you are just going to play with your friends at home?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that a local multiplayer mode will ever require a Nintendo Online subscription, since you are playing offline content. This includes playing on "split-screen" or wireless play across different Nintendo Switch consoles.

According to [this old answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/353134/87579), quoting Overcooked 2 eShop description:

> A Nintendo Switch Online membership (sold separately) is required for online play

So you should need Nintendo Online only for online multiplayer, not the local one.